# PHP Sum keys in multidimensional array that match another key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I have a multidimensional array and I need to add up some of the data.

My array looks like this (there is a lot more data I cropped out for the example):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 20-02-2014
            [tool] => mystuff1
            [usage] => 447
            [minutes] => 6705
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 20-02-2014
            [tool] => mystuff2
            [usage] => 20
            [minutes] => 1200
        )
```

There will be more than one sub-array that has tool=mystuff1 and I want to add the "minutes" key up for all the ones that have mystuff1.  Ultimately I want to do the same with mystuff2 added up (there are other 'tool' keys besides those that will be done as well.)

Ive tried several examples I found on this site but they all seem sum based on the 1 key name i.e. 'minutes' but not anything I can find where I can sum the 'minutes' when 'tool' also matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your array and add the minutes value to the **array key** of an output array:

```
$output = array();

foreach($your_array as $current) {
    // create the array key if it doesn't exist already
    if(!array_key_exists($current['tool'], $output))
        $output[$current['tool']] = 0;

    // add minutes to the current tool total
    $output[$current['tool']] += $current['minutes'];
}
```

This way you can expect a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [mystuff1] => 6705
    [mystuff2] => 1200
)
```

Comment: That works great.  One thing though, if I had a similar setup but wanted to subtract the values from eachother wouldnt I use a -= instead of the +=?  If I do that now I get a negative number instead of the proper results.  ex:  with += I get 13410 with -= I get -13410

Comment: What do you mean by proper results? If I removed a number from zero I'd expect it to be negative...

Comment: well lets say one of them has value of 6500 and the other has a value of 500.  If I += them it is now 7000.  For some reason if I -= it shows -7000.  I would expect 6000 since 6500-500=6000.  Do I misunderstand what that code is actually doing?

Comment: No - your first example is adding both values together, the second is subtracting both values (the loop will perform the same operator every time) - how do you differentiate between which values need to be added or subtracted, and is having `-500` as one of your values not acceptable? (6500 + -500 = 6000)

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Thanks for the code. It works great for the first question.